# Dynamically add private properties to an object

Tags: php, oop, reflection

When you have the following code:

```
<?php

class Foo { public $attribute; }

$o = new Foo();
$o->bar = true;

?>
```

PHP automatically creates a dynamic public property to that object.

Is there any possibility to do add dynamic **private** properties? Or set them to private at runtime with Reflection?

My `__set` method needs to be called every time someone tries to set any attribute in my class. I could set all my attributes to private, but, I have attributes that are added dynamically in this class, and when an attribute is added automatically, it has a public visibility.

This prevents the `__set` method from being called. How can I make dynamic properties call `__set` when receiving a value?

Actually, there's a method on ReflectionProperty class named setAccessible(). I would do the opposite of this method.

Comment: Short answer, no. Long answer, you might be able to use reflection to change the scope of a property.. but reflection shouldn't be used like that unless you're debugging or unit testing.

Comment: What the hell are you trying to do anyways?

Comment: @FabienWarniez just added real info to the question.

Comment: @MikeB That's the idea, but I don't seem to find anything in Reflection documentation about it. There's a method on `ReflectionProperty` class named `setAccessible()`. I want to do the opposite of this method.

Comment: why cannot you just use a private array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't seem possible in current versions of PHP.

While [`ReflectionProperty::setAccessible()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionproperty.setaccessible.php) *does* take a boolean argument, the change it makes only allows Reflection itself to access / not access the value.  It doesn't actually change the accessibility of the actual property.

As a hacky workaround to keep dynamic properties private, consider having your `__set` store properties that don't actually exist in a dedicated private array.  Example code:

```
class Test {

    private $foo;
    public $bar;
    private $_properties;

    public function __get($prop) {
        if(property_exists($this, $prop))
            return $this->$prop;
        if(array_key_exists($prop, $this->_properties))
            return $this->_properties[$prop];
    }

    public function __set($prop, $value) {
        if(!property_exists($this, $prop)) {
            $this->_properties[$prop] = $value;
            echo 'SetDynamic: ', $prop, "\n";
            return;
        }
        $this->$prop = $value; 
        echo 'Set: ', $prop, "\n";
    }

}
```

Running from the PHP interactive prompt:

```
php > $t = new Test;
php > $t->foo = 1;
Set: foo
php > $t->foo = 2;
Set: foo
php > $t->bar = 1;
php > $t->testorama = 1;
SetDynamic: testorama
php > $t->testorama = 2;
SetDynamic: testorama
```

While this will ensure that *external* access *always* goes through your `__get` and `__set` methods, it presents a problem for internal use, as you're now always given two places to check for dynamic properties.  That's why this is a hackish workaround instead of a real solution.

Comment: Although that may not be the best solution, this worked exactly as I needed. I may not call those attributes directly inside the class, they are only used externally and aren't accessed from within the class. Also, now I see that I misunderstood the concept of `setAccessible()` method. Thanks!